# buffer output missing first name

Tags: c, file, memory-management, structure

hi I have this question with reading data into array of structures
This is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME   20
#define FILE_NAME  50
#define LIST_SIZE 50
//void getData(RECORD name[], RECORD score)


typedef struct 
{
    char *name;
    int  score;
}RECORD;


int main (void)
{
    // Declarations
       FILE *fp;
       char fileName[FILE_NAME];
       RECORD list[LIST_SIZE];
       char buffer[50];
       int count = 0;
    // Statements
       printf("Enter the file name: ");
       gets(fileName);

       fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

       if(fp == NULL)
           printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
       while (fgets(buffer, LIST_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
         {   
                     printf("%s\n", buffer);
         list[count].name = (char*) calloc(strlen(buffer), sizeof(char));
         sscanf(buffer,"%s%d", list[count].name, &list[count].score);
         printf("name is: %s and score is:%d \n", list[count].name, list[count].score);
         count++;

         }
       printf("Read in %d data records\n", count);
       return 0;
}
```

so, inside the while loop when i try to print out with out allocating name it seems to work fine, but after i allocate memory for name the buffer is missing the first name when printing out. 
so i have this output

```
Enter the file name: in.txt
Ada Lovelace, 66

Torvalds, 75

Norton, 82

Thompson, 82

Wozniak, 79

Andreessen, 60

Knuth, 60

Goldberg, 71

Hopper, 82

Joy, 91

Tanenbaum, 71

Kernighan, 72
Read in 12 data records
```

instead of the right output which is

```
Enter the file name: in.txt
Ada Lovelace, 66

Linus Torvalds, 75

Peter Norton, 82

Ken Thompson, 82

Steve Wozniak, 79

Marc Andreessen, 60

Donald Knuth, 60

Adele Goldberg, 71

Grace Hopper, 82

Bill Joy, 91

Andrew Tanenbaum, 71

Brian Kernighan, 72
Read in 12 data records
```

This is the output after i commented out the fscanf line, so I think the error may occur there.Is there something thing wrong with the memory allocation process, I'm thinking that I'm doing it wrong.

I fix the fscanf statement now i get

```
Enter the file name: in.txt
Ada Lovelace, 66

name is: Ada and score is:3929744
Linus Torvalds, 75

name is: Linus and score is:3929752
Peter Norton, 82

name is: Peter and score is:3929760
Ken Thompson, 82

name is: Ken and score is:3929768
Steve Wozniak, 79

name is: Steve and score is:3929776
Marc Andreessen, 60

name is: Marc and score is:3929784
Donald Knuth, 60

name is: Donald and score is:3929792
Adele Goldberg, 71

name is: Adele and score is:3929800
Grace Hopper, 82

name is: Grace and score is:3929808
Bill Joy, 91

name is: Bill and score is:3929816
Andrew Tanenbaum, 71

name is: Andrew and score is:3929824
Brian Kernighan, 72
name is: Brian and score is:3929832
Read in 12 data records
```

as you can see the line name is: only print out first name but not last name and the address of integer score.

Comment: `%s` is space character for delimitaer.

Comment: thank that make it work but i still get the address printout for integer score.Actually I edited the printf line and now I get zero for score

Comment: `{
    char *name;
    float  score;
}RECORD;` `score` is float , if integer then change to int score.

Comment: oh yeah thank i forgot to change back to int

Comment: The `%s` conversion stops at the space between first and surname. Then the `%d` conversion fails on the surname, and your `score` contains garbage. a) always check the return value of `(f/s)scanf`; 2) use `%[^,],%d` if `score` is an `int`, or with `%f` instead of `%d` as BLUEPIXY said above if `score` is a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

The fgets and the fscanf are fighting with each other because they're both reading from the file.  Use fgets to read from the file into your buffer, then use sscanf to parse the data into the structure.

In general you should prefer fgets to fscanf because it's safer.  In any case, don't mix fgets and fscanf.

Comment: well i did fix that and also when I commented out  the printf line after sscanf it still give me only the first name and the address of the integer score

Comment: Check the man page for sscanf (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).  The "%s" conversion stops at whitespace unless you give it a width specifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. First of all try using scanf and fscanf if there is a certain pattern in your input file. I have had problems with newline characters when using fgets and gets. Also fscanf reads till it finds either space character or the newline (have you considered this in your code? since it is very obvious why it reads only one of the name segments). It may be that your are using printf with the same problem, it only writes till \n or ' '. 
You might wanna consider using ifstream and sstream if you can use C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
...

while (fgets(buffer, LIST_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
{
    char *tok;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    tok = strchr(buffer, ',');
    if (!tok)
    {
        printf("Bad line\n");
        continue;
    }

    list[count].name = strndup(buffer, tok - buffer);
    list[count].score = atoi(tok + 1);

    printf("name is: %s and score is:%d \n", list[count].name, list[count].score);
    count++;
}
...
```